# Javascript toggle display: block/none

Tags: javascript, toggle

I got a problem with my code below. I want a div element, that appears on clicking on a + sign and disappears when clicking on a x sign. The disappearing part i could figure out. But somehow the appear part doesn't work.
Can someone help me with this problem?

```css
.button {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="element.querySelector('.more').style.display = 'block';" class="button">&plus;
<div id="more">
<span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';" class="button">&times;
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

edit:
Unfortunately the suggested `this.querySelector('#more').style.display = 'block'";` is not working. How can I access the #more id that is NEXT to the button and not the first one in the code?

Comment: Wrong selector: use document.querySelector('#more'). Also, not sure that your HTML is valid (unclosed span tag).https://jsfiddle.net/gvy3cade/

Comment: Where is the `class="more"` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Description

`span` needs to be closed `<span>stuff</span>`

When running `querySelector` you need to use `#` for IDs and `.` for CSS classes.  Running querySelector needs an element to be run on: `this`, `document` are two examples.

```css
.button {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
// need to select by ID #, search the document, close the span
<span onclick="document.querySelector('#more').style.display = 'block';" class="button">&plus;</span>
<div id="more">
// close the span
<span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';" class="button">&times;</span>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

---

### Example using Class, also hiding the plus more intelligently

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.querySelector('.more').style.display = 'block'; this.style.display = 'none';" class="button" style="display: none">&plus;</span>
  <div class="more">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none'; this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('span').style.display = 'block';" class="button">&times;</span>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this.querySelector('#more').style.display = 'block';" class="button">&plus;</span> is not working. I need to stay in this part of the code and don't look in the whole document for the id #more. 
Else it works perfect thanks!

Comment: @DominikFrey absolutely, in reality since you are using an id you could easily just do a `document.getElementById('#more');` which is extremely fast.

Comment: But how do i access the right id if I have more than one id called #more. It will always use the first #more that it can find. I always want to use the #more that is next to the span. Isn't there something like a child function?

Comment: @DominikFrey you shouldn't have more than one of the same ID in the same DOM ever.  If you do, you should instead be using class="more" then searching by `.`

Comment: Okay I'm using class now. Thats right. But how do I access now the class .more right after the span? With `document.querySelector('.more')` I will always access the first .more class and not the one that is right after the span. 
The goal is to have multiple divs with the class .more and display/hide each with its own button.

Comment: @DominikFrey added a second example with the code you are curious about.